# Access C structure from python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, structure, ctypes

I am to create a python script that will access a windows dll function. I was successful in accessing the dll and its functions. Now that, I have a c function as

```
FIOSCR331_API int FIOCreateDeviceInfoList (PDEVINFO pDevInfoSet)
```

the problem is the `PDEVINFO` structure. I must create a structure in python and access this structure.

The C structure is as follows

```
typedef struct tagDEVINFO
{

    char                    szDeviceName[MAX_PATH];
    char                    szPCSCName[MAX_PATH];
    BOOL                    bPassedFilter;
    BOOL                    bUpdatePassed;
    DWORD                   dwUpdateOrder;
    DWORD                   dwPnP_ID;
    DWORD                   dwFWVersion;
    PDEVEXTENSION   pDevExtension;

} DEVINFO, *PDEVINFO;
```

the C function is as follows

```
FIOSCR331_API int FIOCreateDeviceInfoList (PDEVINFO pDevInfoSet)
{

    int nFIOStatus;
    do
    {
            if ( NULL == pDevInfoSet )
            {
                printf("this is inside C code\n");
                    nFIOStatus = IDS_GENERIC_ERROR; //(200)
                    break;
            }
            else
                printf ("\n%s ",pDevInfoSet->szPCSCName);

    }while(false);
}
```

Now the Python code I implemented

```
class DEVINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("szDeviceName",c_char_p),
                ("szPCSCName",c_char_p),
                ("bPassedFilter",c_bool),
                ("bUpdatePassed",c_bool),
                ("dwUpdateOrder",c_ulong),
                ("dwPnp_ID",c_ulong),
                ("dwFWVersion",c_ulong),
                ("pDevExtention",DEVEXTENSION)]

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libFIOXXXXX.dll')
print (lib)
devInfo = DEVINFO()
devInfo.szPCSCName = c_char_p(b"this is test")
if devInfo is None:
    print("hi")
else:
    print("britto")
funcCreateList = lib.FIOCreateDeviceInfoList(devInfo)
print (funcCreateList)
```

The Result I got is

```
britto
this is inside C code
200
```

The problem is the code goes into NULL condition always, i.e. **devInfo is NULL**. Why is that?

**NEWLY ADDED**

In the above python Structure DEVINFO, It contains another structure DEVEXTENSION. How will i be able to access the members of the DEVEXTENSION error??

```
print (devInfo.pDevExtension.szName)
```

This throws:

```
AttributeError: 'LP_DEVEXTENSION" object has no attribute szName
```

Comment: For your follow up question on 10-29, use either `devInfo.pDevExtension[0].szName` or `devInfo.pDevExtension.contents.szName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure declaration is wrong. It should be:

```
class DEVINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("szDeviceName", c_char*wintypes.MAX_PATH),
        ("szPCSCName", c_char*wintypes.MAX_PATH),
        ("bPassedFilter", wintypes.BOOL),
        ("bUpdatePassed", wintypes.BOOL),
        ("dwUpdateOrder", wintypes.DWORD),
        ("dwPnp_ID", wintypes.DWORD),
        ("dwFWVersion", wintypes.DWORD),
        ("pDevExtension", POINTER(DEVEXTENSION))
    ]
```

You must also pass a pointer to the `DEVINFO` struct when you call `FIOCreateDeviceInfoList()`. I'd do it like this:

```
funcCreateList = lib.FIOCreateDeviceInfoList(byref(devInfo))
```

As @eryksun helpfully points out, adding

```
lib.FIOCreateDeviceInfoList.argtypes = [POINTER(DEVINFO)]
```

before the call to `FIOCreateDeviceInfoList()` will make `ctypes` perform runtime type checking.

Comment: To be type safe set `lib.FIOCreateDeviceInfoList.argtypes = [POINTER(DEVINFO)]`.

Comment: @eryksun Will that apply runtime type checking?

Comment: Yes: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_DEVINFO instance instead of str`. It beats a segfault.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks. I hadn't considered that. But you make an excellent point.

Comment: @Britto: Note that this creates character arrays inline in the memory allocated for the structure. Don't set the value with a `c_char_p`; just use, for example, `devInfo.szPCSCName = b"this is a test"`. The `_ctypes.CField` handles copying the bytes into the structure.

Comment: @all Thank you guys. Me being a beginner in python that was greatly hepful.

Comment: @eryksun & David: wintypes dont exist for linux. I want my script to be run in linux too. How would my structure resemble in that case?

Comment: Well, that struct clearly only has meaning on Windows. It uses `MAX_PATH` which is Windows specific. The C++ header file clearly #includes windows.h. Presumably you want to work with some other struct. You'd just need to translate that appropriately. I don't think we can do that in comments to this question. Sounds like you have a new question.

Comment: @Britto: Here's the [wintypes source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d0686d90f55/Lib/ctypes/wintypes.py) if you need to manually define the types and constants (e.g. `MAX_PATH = 260`).

Answer (score 0):

Tell ctypes that the type of the argument to `FIOCreateDeviceInfoList` is a pointer to a DEVINFO structure by setting its `argtypes` attribute as follows:

```
lib.FIOCreateDeviceInfoList.argtypes = [POINTER(DEVINFO)]
```